# Discrete math proof help: $A∖ (B ∖ C) = (A∖ B) \cup (A \cap C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> $A∖ (B ∖ C) = (A∖ B) \cup (A \cap C)$ where $A,B,C$ are sets.

I'll be honest. I don't know how to prove it. so I tried to play with left side and bring it to right without much success:

$ A\backslash (B\backslash C)=A \cap (B\backslash C)^c = A \cap (B \cap C^c)^c=A \cap (B^c \cup C)$

Comment: What is supposed to be $U$? A set that contains $A$ and $B$?

Comment: its global terming for universe

Comment: Don't use the term "group" for $A,B,C$, because it has a certain mathematical meaning. Use "set" or "collection" instead.

Comment: Wait a minute, why did you replace your old question with a completely different one? This is considered **vandalism**. **Do not do this again**.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You can continue from your current progress by using distributivity:

$A∩(B^c∪C) = (A∩B^c)∪(A∩C)$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: thank you i just managed to go to this step,but no idea about $$ (A∩B^c) $$ to $$ A\backslash B $$

Comment: @anton5450: Well, what is the definition of $A∖B$??

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have $A^C\subset A^C\cup B^C\subset A$, this implies $A^C=\emptyset$, as $A,A^C$ is disjoint.